# Simple accordion doesn't close properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've a task to create simple accordion without using existing examples. The idea is not new. There are `title` and `description` elements in DOM. After click on title the description open. Click again on this title shut description. Click on another title shuts opened description and opens description of title, that was clicked. So I write next code, that opens description via click on title, shuts it when click on another title and open related description. But have next issut. I click on title and description is opened. I click again on this title, but description isn't shut.

This is my DOM:

```js
    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            var $title = $('.accordion .title');
            var $desc = $('.desc');
            var activateClass = 'active';
            function accordion() {
                $title.click(function() {
                    $this = $(this);
                    
                    if ($desc.hasClass(activateClass)) {
                     $desc.removeClass(activateClass);
                    }
    
                    if ($this.next().hasClass(activeClass)) {
                     $this.next().removeClass(activeClass)
                    } else {
                     $this.next().addClass();
                    }
                    
                });
            }
    
            accordion();
        });
    
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul li.title {
        border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
        background: #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin: 0 10px 0px 10px;
        padding: 6px 8px;
    }
    
    ul li.desc {
        display: none;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    
    ul li.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
        <li class="title">Title-1</li>
        <li class="desc">Description-1
        <li class="title">Title-2</li>
        <li class="desc">Description-2</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: at a quick glance it looks like it's because you have everything at the same level. try dropping the description down one level. nest them

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives an error `undefined activeClass` please always keep eyes on console errors .. And instead of all checking for classes you can use just both lines of code

```
$('.desc').not($this.next('.desc')).removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all desc elements but not the one which next to the title you click
$this.next('.desc').toggleClass('active'); // toggleClass active to desc next to the title clicked
```

***Working example***

```js
$(function() {
    var $title = $('.accordion .title');
    var $desc = $('.desc');

    function accordion() {
        $title.click(function() {
           $this = $(this);
           $desc.not($this.next('.desc')).removeClass('active');
           $this.next('.desc').toggleClass('active');
        });
    }
    
    accordion();
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li.title {
    border: 1px solid #0F0F0F;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 0 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}

ul li.desc {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}

ul li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
    <li class="title">Title-1</li>
    <li class="desc">Description-1
    <li class="title">Title-2</li>
    <li class="desc">Description-2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohamed-Yousef